# Data type conversion uint8_t/uint16_t to char[] via snprintf

Tags: c, char, printf, type-conversion, uint8t

```
char data[40] = {'\0'};
uint8_t Plevel= 0xA5;
uint8_t status = 0x21;
uint16_t ID = 0xABCD;

snprintf(data, 5, "%"PRIu8"%"PRIu8"%"PRIu16"",Plevel, status, ID );
printf("data:%s\n",data);
```

outputs: 1653

I use http://www.asciitohex.com/ to see the conversion but couldn't get why it outputs 1653.

Could anyone please explain the conversions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xA5` outputs 165. `0x21` outputs 33. `0xABCD` outputs 43981. This gives `1653343981`. But your output string size is restricted to `5` (including the `nul` terminator) and so you get `1653`.

Comment: thank you:) it is not part of my question, but I would be happy if you could answer it as well. My aim is to store uin8_t as 1 byte (I am trying to do data serialization). Do I need an hex to ASCII converter or can I store it differently via snprintf instead of using "PRIu8"?

Comment: The type `uint8_t` ***is*** stored as one byte. It makes no difference whether you assign a value as hex `0xA5` or a decimal `165`. They both represent the same value. The one byte neither stores `0xA5` nor `165` literally: it holds a bit pattern representing the value.

Comment: I meant, to pass 0xA5 into "data", it requires 3 byte space (string length) on snprintf. but I want to keep it as 1 character instead of 3. Can I use anything else than %"PRIu8" on snprintf for it? or do I need an hex to ASCII converter?

Comment: You can put one or more bytes into a char array (`data[0]=Plevel;`), but you won't be able to use any string functions since the data won't be textual.

Comment: I use snprintf to pass the data to a UDP socket, it is fine if the data is not texual. Do you know if I can pass 0xA5 to the char array as 1 element via snprintf or do I need an ASCII converter?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are asking. `snprint(..."%u")` and similar convert a number to ASCII text. You don't need `snprintf()` to put one byte into an array. You just put it in the array.

Comment: Similarly, if you want to put the 16 bit value into a char array, you can do it with `data[0]=ID/256; data[1]=ID%256;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83787/discussion-between-sven-and-weather-vane).